# Extension not working on the Server. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, extensions, checkout-page

I created a simple extension to just add an extra **Radio Button** in checkout. my code is

> CheckoutJazz/Radio/registration.php

```
<?php 
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'CheckoutJazz_Radio',
    __DIR__
);
```

> CheckoutJazz/Radio/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="CheckoutJazz_Radio" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

> CheckoutJazz/Radio/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="payments-list" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">CheckoutJazz_Radio/js/view/payment/list</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> CheckoutJazz/Radio/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/list.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'ko',
    'mageUtils',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-list',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list',
    'uiLayout',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'mage/translate',
    'uiRegistry'
], function ($, _, ko, utils, Component, paymentMethods, rendererList, layout, checkoutDataResolver, $t, registry) {
    'use strict';


    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'CheckoutJazz_Radio/payment-methods/list',
            visible: paymentMethods().length > 0,
            configDefaultGroup: {
                name: 'methodGroup',
                component: 'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-group'
            },
            paymentGroupsList: [],
            defaultGroupTitle: $t('Select a new payment method')
        },


        // The below function is added by Asad
        show_hide_fun: function(){

             if( $("#show_hide_jazz").attr('checked') ) {
                $("#custom_jazz_s").show();
                $("#custom_jazz_m").show();
                // $("#custom_jazz_c").show();
                $("#myJazz").hide();
            } else {
                $("#custom_jazz_s").hide();
                $("#custom_jazz_m").hide();
                // $("#custom_jazz_c").hide();
            }
         },

        /**
         * Initialize view.
         *
         * @returns {Component} Chainable.
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super().initDefaulGroup().initChildren();
            paymentMethods.subscribe(
                function (changes) {
                    checkoutDataResolver.resolvePaymentMethod();
                    //remove renderer for "deleted" payment methods
                    _.each(changes, function (change) {
                        if (change.status === 'deleted') {
                            this.removeRenderer(change.value.method);
                        }
                    }, this);
                    //add renderer for "added" payment methods
                    _.each(changes, function (change) {
                        if (change.status === 'added') {
                            this.createRenderer(change.value);
                        }
                    }, this);
                }, this, 'arrayChange');

            return this;
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        initObservable: function () {
            this._super().
                observe(['paymentGroupsList']);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Creates default group
         *
         * @returns {Component} Chainable.
         */
        initDefaulGroup: function () {
            layout([
                this.configDefaultGroup
            ]);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Create renders for child payment methods.
         *
         * @returns {Component} Chainable.
         */
        initChildren: function () {
            var self = this;

            _.each(paymentMethods(), function (paymentMethodData) {
                self.createRenderer(paymentMethodData);
            });

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * @returns
         */
        createComponent: function (payment) {
            var rendererTemplate,
                rendererComponent,
                templateData;

            templateData = {
                parentName: this.name,
                name: payment.name
            };
            rendererTemplate = {
                parent: '${ $.$data.parentName }',
                name: '${ $.$data.name }',
                displayArea: payment.displayArea,
                component: payment.component
            };
            rendererComponent = utils.template(rendererTemplate, templateData);
            utils.extend(rendererComponent, {
                item: payment.item,
                config: payment.config
            });

            return rendererComponent;
        },

        /**
         * Create renderer.
         *
         * @param {Object} paymentMethodData
         */
        createRenderer: function (paymentMethodData) {
            var isRendererForMethod = false,
                currentGroup;

            registry.get(this.configDefaultGroup.name, function (defaultGroup) {
                _.each(rendererList(), function (renderer) {

                    if (renderer.hasOwnProperty('typeComparatorCallback') &&
                        typeof renderer.typeComparatorCallback == 'function'
                    ) {
                        isRendererForMethod = renderer.typeComparatorCallback(renderer.type, paymentMethodData.method);
                    } else {
                        isRendererForMethod = renderer.type === paymentMethodData.method;
                    }

                    if (isRendererForMethod) {
                        currentGroup = renderer.group ? renderer.group : defaultGroup;

                        this.collectPaymentGroups(currentGroup);

                        layout([
                            this.createComponent(
                                {
                                    config: renderer.config,
                                    component: renderer.component,
                                    name: renderer.type,
                                    method: paymentMethodData.method,
                                    item: paymentMethodData,
                                    displayArea: currentGroup.displayArea
                                }
                            )]);
                    }
                }.bind(this));
            }.bind(this));
        },

        /**
         * Collects unique groups of available payment methods
         *
         * @param {Object} group
         */
        collectPaymentGroups: function (group) {
            var groupsList = this.paymentGroupsList(),
                isGroupExists = _.some(groupsList, function (existsGroup) {
                    return existsGroup.alias === group.alias;
                });

            if (!isGroupExists) {
                groupsList.push(group);
                groupsList = _.sortBy(groupsList, function (existsGroup) {
                    return existsGroup.sortOrder;
                });
                this.paymentGroupsList(groupsList);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Returns payment group title
         *
         * @param {Object} group
         * @returns {String}
         */
        getGroupTitle: function (group) {
            var title = group().title;

            if (group().isDefault() && this.paymentGroupsList().length > 1) {
                title = this.defaultGroupTitle;
            }

            return title + ':';
        },

        /**
         * Checks if at least one payment method available
         *
         * @returns {String}
         */
        isPaymentMethodsAvailable: function () {
            return _.some(this.paymentGroupsList(), function (group) {
                return this.getRegion(group.displayArea)().length;
            }, this);
        },

        /**
         * Remove view renderer.
         *
         * @param {String} paymentMethodCode
         */
        removeRenderer: function (paymentMethodCode) {
            var items;

            _.each(this.paymentGroupsList(), function (group) {
                items = this.getRegion(group.displayArea);

                _.find(items(), function (value) {
                    if (value.item.method.indexOf(paymentMethodCode) === 0) {
                        value.disposeSubscriptions();
                        value.destroy();
                    }
                });
            }, this);
        }
    });
});
```

> CheckoutJazz/Radio/view/frontend/web/template/payment-methods/list.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
 -->

 <h2>Asad Testing</h2>
 <div if="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()"
 class="items payment-methods">
<div repeat="foreach: paymentGroupsList, item: '$group'"
     class="payment-group">
    <div if="getRegion($group().displayArea)().length"
         translate="getGroupTitle($group)"
         class="step-title"
         data-role="title">
    </div>

    <!-- this below div is added by Asad -->
    <div class="myJazz" id="myJazz"><label for="show_hide_jazz">
        <input type="radio" name="payment[method]" id="show_hide_jazz" data-bind="event: { change: show_hide_fun }"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b4/JazzCash_logo.png" alt="Jazz Cash" width="100px" height="50px"/></label>
    </div>
    <each args="data: getRegion($group().displayArea), as: 'method'" render=""/>
</div>
</div>
<div ifnot="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()"
 class="no-payments-block"
 translate="'No Payment Methods'">
</div>
```

now this extension works perfectly on my localhost but when I tried to run this extension on server then it do not run on checkout page the core file runs.
**Note:** on server I disabled all the extensions but still this extension do not run.

Comment: Please try to change Vendor name from "CheckoutJazz"  to "Checkoutjazz" may it can be only capitalize problem.

Answer (score 0):

After uploading your files, have you run the following on your server:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I do run this command many times n when I tried to check `php bin/magento module:status` in that the extension is also enabled but it is not overriding the class..

Answer (score 0):

sometimes adding a component to checkout requires

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

and make sure you are in a developer mode and empty browser cache

Answer (score -1):

Run the cache that are on server, for example :

```
sudo service php-fpm restart
sudo service varnish restart
```